# Using a repository cloned with gcloud source repos cannot find credential-gcloud.sh

Tags: osx-elcapitan, github-desktop

When syncing a repository in GitHub Desktop that was cloned with `gcloud source repos clone <repository>` the following error comes up on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan):

```
git: 'credential-gcloud.sh' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
2016-08-04 07:44:06.598 GitHub Desktop Login[809:15686] AskPass with arguments: (
    "/Applications/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub Desktop Login",
    "Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': "
)
2016-08-04 07:44:06.645 GitHub Desktop Login[809:15686] Error getting keychain item for source.developers.google.com: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
error: unable to read askpass response from '/Applications/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub Desktop Login'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': Device not configured
 (128)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the credential helper git-credential-gcloud.sh delivered with gcloud SDK cannot be found on the PATH.

Fortunately git cannot only call and detect a credential helper from the PATH, but also accepts and invokes commands when specified a full path.

Changing the credential.helper from:

```
credential.helper="gcloud.sh"
```

to:

```
credential.helper=/<PATH-TO-GCLOUD-SDK>/bin/git-credential-gcloud.sh
```

by invoking

```
git config credential.helper /<PATH-TO-GCLOUD-SDK>/bin/git-credential-gcloud.sh
```

resolves the issue for the specific repository.